# object references an unsaved transient instance error

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa, jboss

Ok so i want to get mapped Groups and student in one table but i've got an error: "object references an unsaved transient instance". If i add cascade to all it will say that this objects arleady exists. What is wrong ?

Here are entities:

```
 @Entity  
 @Table(name = "listaosob") 
 public class listaOsob implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private int id;
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@ManyToOne
private Student student;
@ManyToOne
private Grupa grupa;

@Entity  
@Table(name = "student") 
public class Student implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue
private int id;
private String imie;
private String nazwisko;
private String login;
private String haslo;
@Column(unique=true)
private int nr_albumu;
@Column(unique=true)
private String kod_karty;

 @Entity  
 @Table(name = "grupa") 
 public class Grupa implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue
private int id;
private String nazwa;
private Time godzina;
private String sala;
private String tydzien;
@ManyToOne
private Prowadzacy prowadzacy;
```

ejb code:

```
 @Stateless
 @LocalBean
 public class StudentBean implements StudentBeanRemote, StudentBeanLocal {

 @PersistenceContext  
 private EntityManager eM; 

public StudentBean() {}

public void dodajStudenta(Student s) {
    eM.persist(s);
    eM.flush();
}

public void usunStudenta(Student s) {
    eM.remove(s);  
    eM.flush();
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public ArrayList<Student> listaStudentow() {
    Query query = eM.createQuery("SELECT e FROM student e");
    return (ArrayList<Student>) query.getResultList();
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public ArrayList<Student> listaStudentow(Grupa grupa) {
    Query query = eM.createQuery("SELECT e FROM listaosob e WHERE e.grupa = :grupa");
    query.setParameter("grupa", grupa);
    return (ArrayList<Student>) query.getResultList();
}

public void dodajGrupe(Grupa g) {
    eM.persist(g);
}

public void usunGrupe(Grupa g) {
    eM.remove(g);  
    eM.flush();
}

public void dodajListeOsob(listaOsob l) {
    eM.persist(l);
}
```

and a example test:

```
Student name1 = new Student("new"+gen.nextInt(),"nazwisko","log", "haslo", "asd"+gen.nextInt(), gen.nextInt());
            obj.dodajStudenta(name1);
            Grupa n = new Grupa();
            obj.dodajGrupe(n);
            listaOsob lista = new listaOsob(name1, n);
            obj.dodajListeOsob(lista);
```

Comment: 1) The code snippet you have provided is not complete, dodajListeOsob is missing. 2) Is the example test code called from the container managed code? 3) Which line throws "object references an unsaved transient instance" and which one "objects arleady exists"?

Comment: 1) sory, i just add method on the bottom:
public void dodajListeOsob(listaOsob l) {
     eM.persist(l);
    }
2) example is called remotely from standalone aplication
3) obj.dodajListeOsob(lista); throws both errors but object arleady exists only if i add cascade.ALL to @manytoone()

Comment: it seems to work if i remove @GeneratedValue from id fields.

Answer (score 0):

`dodajListeOsob` throws `object references an unsaved transient instance`

- because `listaOsob` contains `grupa` (`@ManyToOne`), which is not present in the database
- `grupa` is not present in the database, because `dodajGrupe` does not do `persist` like the other methods do
- also `dodajListeOsob` does not call `persist` (in this scenario it will not cause any issues)

Comment: Are you talking about set of persist, flush ? Even if i add flush to all methods, object still doesnt persist to database, its in transient state propably because it waiting to get generated id. If the set of persist, flush doesnt save what should i do to persist object instantly ?